# Create a 3d general rotation using open gl

Tags: python, opengl, 3d, rotation

I have this python code and I'm trying to implement the function rotate that receives theta, x, y, z. I'm trying to implement the function based on the next math theory:

Trying to get to this `R(theta)=T^-1 * Rx^-1(alpha) *  Ry^-1(betha) *  Rz(theta) * Ry(betha) * Rx(alpha) * T`

First we get the Vector by sqrt(p1-p2), where p1 is the initial points and p2 the new points.

Then we get the unit vectors:

```
a=x2-x1/V
b=y2-y1/V
c=z2-z1/V
d=sqrt(b^2*c^2)
```

This getting to this:

```
 Rx_inv_alpha = np.array([[1, 0, 0, 0],
                             [0, c/d, -b/d, 0],
                             [0, b/d, c/d, 0],
                             [0, 0, 0, 1]])

    Ry_inv_beta = np.array([[d, 0, a, 0],
                            [0, 1, 0, 0],
                            [-a, 0, d, 0],
                            [0, 0, 0, 1]])

    Rz_theta = np.array([[np.cos(np.radians(theta)), -np.sin(np.radians(theta)), 0, 0],
                         [np.sin(np.radians(theta)), np.cos(np.radians(theta)), 0, 0],
                         [0, 0, 1, 0],
                         [0, 0, 0, 1]])

    Ry_beta = np.array([[d, 0, -a, 0],
                       [0, 1, 0, 0],
                       [a, 0, d, 0],
                       [0, 0, 0, 1]])

    Rx_alpha = np.array([[1, 0, 0, 0],
                         [0, c/d, b/d, 0],
                         [0, -b/d, c/d, 0],
                         [0, 0, 0, 1]])
```

The problem that I have is that trying to implement this I get an error in certain calls to  my class in python.

This is the code:

```py
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *
from OpenGL.GLUT import *

import math
import numpy as np

class OpMat:
    def __init__(self, ):
        self.T = np.identity(4) #transicion
        self.R = np.identity(4) #rotacion
        self.S = np.identity(4) #escala
        self.A = np.identity(4) #acumuladora
        
    def translate(self, tx, ty, tz):
        self.T = np.identity(4)
        self.T[0][3] = tx
        self.T[1][3] = ty
        self.T[2][3] = tz
        self.A = self.T @ self.A

    def rotateX(self, deg):
        self.R = np.identity(4)
        radians = np.radians(deg)
        self.R[1][1] = np.cos(radians)
        self.R[1][2] = -1 * np.sin(radians)
        self.R[2][1] = np.sin(radians)
        self.R[2][2] = np.cos(radians)
        self.A = self.R @ self.A
    
    def rotateY(self, deg):
        self.R = np.identity(4)
        radians = np.radians(deg)
        self.R[0][0] = np.cos(radians)
        self.R[0][2] = np.sin(radians)
        self.R[2][0] = -1 * np.sin(radians)
        self.R[2][2] = np.cos(radians)
        self.A = self.R @ self.A
        
    def rotateZ(self, deg):
        self.R = np.identity(4)
        radians = np.radians(deg)
        self.R[0][0] = np.cos(radians)
        self.R[0][1] = -1 * np.sin(radians)
        self.R[1][0] = np.sin(radians)
        self.R[1][1] = np.cos(radians)
        self.A = self.R @ self.A
    
    def rotate(self, theta, x, y, z):
        self.translate(-x, -y, -z)

        dx = x
        dy = y
        dz = z
        V = np.sqrt(dx**2 + dy**2 + dz**2)

        a = dx / V
        b = dy / V
        c = dz / V
        d = np.sqrt(b**2 + c**2)
        
        print("a:", a, "b:", b, "c:", c, "d:", d)

        if np.isclose(d, 0):
            Rx_inv_alpha = np.identity(4)
            Ry_inv_beta = np.identity(4)
        else:
            Rx_inv_alpha = np.array([[1, 0, 0, 0],
                                    [0, c/d, -b/d, 0],
                                    [0, b/d, c/d, 0],
                                    [0, 0, 0, 1]])

            Ry_inv_beta = np.array([[d, 0, a, 0],
                                    [0, 1, 0, 0],
                                    [-a, 0, d, 0],
                                    [0, 0, 0, 1]])

        Rz_theta = np.array([[np.cos(np.radians(theta)), -np.sin(np.radians(theta)), 0, 0],
                            [np.sin(np.radians(theta)), np.cos(np.radians(theta)), 0, 0],
                            [0, 0, 1, 0],
                            [0, 0, 0, 1]])

        Ry_beta = np.array([[d, 0, -a, 0],
                        [0, 1, 0, 0],
                        [a, 0, d, 0],
                        [0, 0, 0, 1]])

        Rx_alpha = np.array([[1, 0, 0, 0],
                            [0, c/d, b/d, 0],
                            [0, -b/d, c/d, 0],
                            [0, 0, 0, 1]])

        T_inv = np.linalg.inv(self.T)

        rotation_matrix = T_inv @ Rx_inv_alpha @ Ry_inv_beta @ Rz_theta @ Ry_beta @ Rx_alpha @ self.T

        self.A = rotation_matrix @ self.A

        self.translate(x, y, z)



    
    def scale(self, sx, sy, sz):
        self.S = np.identity(4)
        self.S[0][0] = sx
        self.S[1][1] = sy
        self.S[2][2] = sz
        self.A = self.S @ self.A
    
    def mult_Points(self, points):
        pointsR = (self.A @ points.T).T #points and result transposed
        for i in range(0, pointsR.shape[1] + 1):
            for j in range(0, 4):
                points[i][j] = pointsR[i][j]
    
    def loadIdentity(self):
        self.A = np.identity(4)
```

Comment: What error do you get in certain calls?

Do you always get an error, or only for particular values?

Do you get different errors with different values?